# Create a message box that user can choose to "Don't show it again."

Tags: c#, winforms

Made a mass messenger & a multi-message/spammer in one, works fine, just want to make it even better. Obviously I had to write code to have skype allow the program so it can do what it does, here it is,

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //I entered a message box so it doesn't crash instantly.
        MessageBox.Show("Please allow SkypeBot.vshost.exe to access skype. (Look at your Skype application)");
        Skype skype = new Skype();
        skype.Attach();
        getContacts(skype);
    }
```

how can I make it stop showing the MessageBox and just go straight to loading the form if the user already allowed it in the past (since it doesn't ask to allow it anymore after you've allowed it once)

here is what it looks like, if any are wondering, for some reason;
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gurgQ.jpg,
works fine, just want to improve it so any answers to the requests above are appreciated :D

Comment: Please **do not** repeat tags in question titles. Provide a *sensible* subject summarizing your question. Post **one** question at a time.

Comment: Is your `ListBox` data bounded? How could you detect it the user allowed that setting, is it enough if the user somehow say done?

Comment: @RezaAghaei
uses a simple void method called getContacts(Skype skype) (obviously using skype4com.dll or else none of this would work)

    listBox1.DataSource = Contacts; 

is a line from it if thats what you mean by data bounded

Comment: How could you detect it the user allowed that setting, is it enough if the user somehow say don't ask me again?

Comment: Oh youre talking about the process allow thing? I dont know how it detects it, it just does automatically using the code displayed in the main post.
Basically when I run the app, itll show the messagebox before loading the form saying the message in quotes, then on skype a yellow bar will appear asking to allow/deny it, if the user clicks allow, the form will load, but if not, it wont. I dont know how it detects what the user presses though, thats kinda what im asking too because I would need to know how so I can add if user clicks allow, dont send messagebox anymore @RezaAghaei

Comment: So showing a message box with a check box that user can check "Don't show it again" is acceptable?

Comment: I would assume so, but I dont know the code to add a checkbox to show on the messagebox and as well with the code to make sure it actually doesnt show again. @RezaAghaei

Comment: No problem, I'll post some answer for you, but before, since this 2 questions are not related, it's better to edit your question and only ask one of them here and open a new question for the other. Questions and answer should be useful for future readers and having 2 unrelated question in a post is not useful.

Comment: @RDR I posted the answer to this question, hope you find it helpful:) Also I'll answer your other question about sorting if you post it :)

Comment: @RDR It would be great to accept and vote for answer if you find the answer helpful :) Also let me know if you have any question about the answer :)

Answer (score 5):

You can prevent showing the message by adding a check box to the dialog so the user can choose "Don't show this message again". Then you can save the value of the check box in settings and based on that setting, decide to show or not to show the dialog.

As a simple solution, you can create your own custom message box:

1. Create a new `Form` and name it `MessageForm` as your custom message box and put buttons like "OK" button and other buttons if you want. And for each button set proper value for [`DialogResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) property. So when you show your form using `ShowDialog` if you click on a button, without writing code, the form will close with that dialog result.
2. Add a bool [setting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397757(v=vs.110).aspx) to your project `Settings` file, for example name it `DontShow`.
3. Put a check box on form and set its text to "Don't show this message again" and then handle `CheckedChanged` event and save the value of check box in the `DontShow` setting:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.DontShow = this.checkBox1.Checked;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Now you can show your `MessageForm` this way:

```
if(!Properties.Settings.Default.DontShow)
    new MessageForm().ShowDialog();
```

You can enhance your `MessageForm` by accepting the message in constructor or even adding a `public static void ShowMessage(string)` to it to use it like message box.

[image]