# Is there a way to add "do not ask again" checkbox to the standard messagebox?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have to add "do not ask again" checkbox to a messagebox. Is there a way to achieve this with code? Or have i to create an own control? Maybe someone knows another control which has this feature.

Comment: Create your own Form and display it using ShowModal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a message box that user can choose to "Don't show it again."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33962193/create-a-message-box-that-user-can-choose-to-dont-show-it-again)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that, there is not one out of the box to use, for one has to create a new control which displays the main message and has a checkbox for the don't do again.

Of course you will need to put in code to determine and maintain the state which the checkbox will be bound to.